# Is it possible to customise Look Up in macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, look-up

When I three-finger tap on a word, I get a variety of definitions, from Dictionary.app, Siri knowledge, News, the App Store, etc.

Would there be any way, either through Settings or through developing an app, to take away certain functionalities (such as link previewing and news), and add certain functionalities (like searching a specific website, such as a specific online dictionary)?

Note: This article says I can turn off Siri and customise the dictionaries, but I'd like to do more than that:

- https://www.macworld.com/article/3297058/ios-how-to-declutter-look-up.html

Comment: In system preferences->spotlight, some of them can be removed by turning off "allow spotlight in look up"